Computing the nth Fibonacci number using forward recursion with memoization
Question: Is it possible to compute the nth Fibonacci number using forward recursion with memoization? If so, how? If not, why not?
Context: Most learning resources and books (e.g., CLRS, DPV, etc.) introduce dynamic programming (DP) using so-called backward recursion, where we start at the goal and work towards the base cases, but forward recursion instead starts from the base cases and works toward the goal (this is further discussed on Codeforces as well as the OR stack exchange).
For example, house robber is a classic problem where a DP solution makes sense. We can use backward recursion with memoization in the following way:
def rob(nums):
    def dp(house):
        if house <= 1:
            return max(nums[:house+1])
        
        if house in memo:
            return memo[house]
        
        memo[house] = max(nums[house] + dp(house - 2), dp(house - 1))
        return memo[house]
        
    memo = dict()
    return dp(len(nums) - 1)

Or we can use forward recursion with memoization as follows:
def rob(nums):
    def dp(house):
        if house >= n:
            return 0
        
        if house in memo:
            return memo[house]
        
        memo[house] = max(nums[house] + dp(house + 2), dp(house + 1))
        return memo[house]
        
    n = len(nums)
    memo = dict()
    return dp(0)

These approaches reflect different ways of thinking about the same idea. For forward recursion, we think chronologically about where we started and what choices we have from there (e.g., whether to rob or skip the first house). For backward recursion, we start by thinking about the entire solution and about the last choice that led us to our goal (e.g., whether we robbed or skipped the last house). The practical difference between the snippets of code above is that indices are flipped everywhere and the goal and base cases are on opposite ends.
Which brings us to the Fibonacci numbers and the purpose of this question. Computing the nth Fibonacci number is straightforward by means of backward recursion with memoization:
def fib(n):
    def dp(i):
        if i < 2:
            return i
        
        if i in memo:
            return memo[i]
        
        memo[i] = dp(i - 1) + dp(i - 2)
        return memo[i]
    
    memo = dict()
    return dp(n)

What would it mean to "flip indices everywhere" and have the goal and base cases be on opposite ends? For Fibonacci numbers, the base cases are precisely F_0 = 0 and F_1 = 1, where any other Fibonacci number is explicitly the sum of the previous two Fibonacci numbers. Is it possible to compute the nth Fibonacci number using forward recursion with memoization?
The following is my attempt:
def fib(n):
    def dp(i):
        if i >= n:
            return i - n
        
        if i in memo:
            return memo[i]
        
        memo[i] = dp(i + 1) + dp(i + 2)
        return memo[i]
    
    memo = dict()
    return dp(0)

But I'm not really sure this adheres to what is expected of forward DP in this instance. The snippet above computes Fibonacci values correctly, but it leads to highly bizarre and arguably unnatural things like computing memo[n - 1] = dp(n) + dp(n + 1), which results in letting dp(n) = 0 and dp(n + 1) = 1 to ensure the base cases work out. Is the snippet I wrote above what would be expected of a forward DP solution that uses memoization to find the nth Fibonacci number? Or have I misunderstood what is meant by "forward" recursion in this instance?

You have several questions: (1) Does it make sense to compute the nth Fibonacci number using forward recursion with memoization? (2) Does anyone have a good explanation for all of this? A question on SO should be just one question. Moreover, "does it make sense" seems a matter of opinion (as your definition of making sense seems something different than that it is effective). And "all of this" is too broad anyhow. Can you focus on one specific question?

@trincot What you noted as question (1) is the question explicitly delineated at the beginning of the post as well as in the title to the question post itself. Everything else is in service of answering that specific, narrowly-defined question (even if it seems like it may be a matter of opinion to some degree). I have not seen too many resources on forward DP in the literature so I was hoping someone with more experience could remark on the specific problem I mentioned in my question (the idea being that such remarks would be more technical than opinionated in nature).

Can you edit your question and remove the parts that make it a matter of opinion (which is a closure reason on SO), and remove broad questions like on "all of this"?

@trincot OK. I tried removing the overtly opinionated bits from the post. Hopefully it will be more technically sound and less worthy of closure now.

DP works on a DAG(Directed Acyclic Graph) Graph and where to start makes no difference.
For example, this is the DAG for the Fibonacci problem:

Solve this problem from 0 to 5:
Solve(0): Corner case, return 1
Solve(1): Corner case, return 1
Solve(2): Solve(0) + Solve(1), 1 + 1,return 2
Solve(3): Solve(1) + Solve(2), 1 + 2,return 3
...

Solve this problem from 5 to 0:
Solve(5): Solve(4) + Solve(3), ? + ?, recursion.
Solve(4): Solve(3) + Solve(2), ? + ?, recursion.
...
Solve(0): Corner case, return 1

It's essentially the same.

With forward DP you need to make extra effort to make sure your algorithm does not calculate anything beyond what's strictly needed.
With backward DP you get this for free.
An example, calculating the (i+1,j+1) entry of Pascal triangle. The simplest and most trivial forward algorithm will calculate the whole triangle up to and including the jth row.
But the backward algorithm will only calculate the needed "rhombus" area in the triangle, all by its lonesome self.
